# What does electrostatic self-energy mean?

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, mass-energy

The question at hand is:

"Assume that the rest-mass energy $mc^2$ of the electron is equal to its electrostatic self-energy and that the electron charge is distributed uniformly inside a sphere of radius R. What is the value of R (in unit of meter)?"

My question is, what is electrostatic self-energy? Would this be equivalent to integrating $kQ/r$ over the volume of a sphere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What is electrostatic self-energy?

The self energy of a particle means the energy possessed due to interactions between the particle an the system it is part of. ***In electrostatics, self energy  of a particular charge distribution is the energy of required to assemble the charges from infinity to that particular configuration, without accelerating the charges***. It is simply called the electrostatic potential energy stored in the system of charges.

For a simple example, consider an electrostatic field $\vec{E}$ due to some charge $q$. We need to know the electrostatic energy stored in the system of the charges $q$ and some another charge $Q$. Then, we assume we start from infinity (where the electric field due to the charge $q$ is zero). To assemble the charge $Q$ from infinity to a point at a distance $r$ from the charge $q$, we need to do work against the the electric field $\vec{E}$.

We have for electrostatic fields, $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$, where $V$ is a scalar function called the electric potential. The charge $Q$ at any point in the electric field of $q$ experience a force $\vec{F}=Q\vec{E}$ and the work is to be done against this force to assemble the charges in the required configuration. Hence the work done is

$$
\begin{align}
W=-\int_\infty^r \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} &=-Q\int_\infty^r \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r}\\
&=-Q\int_\infty^r (-\nabla V)\cdot d\vec{r}\\
&=-Q\int_\infty^r dV\\
&=Q[V(r)-V(\infty)]
\end{align}
$$

Assuming $V(\infty)=0$, we have the work done

$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]
{
W=QV(r)
\qquad(1) 
}
$$ 
This work done is stored as the *potential energy of the system of the charges*.  We can extend the result to any number of charges and to any configuration. For example, we can find the electrostatic self energy or the energy needed to assemble a system of four charges at the corners of a square.

We know that the electric potential $V$ is the potential energy per unit charge, and the electric potential at some distance $r$ from a charge $q$ is

$$V(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}\qquad(2)$$

Hence equation $(1)$ becomes

$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
W=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\frac{qQ}{r}
\qquad(3)
}
$$

This is the **electrostatic self energy of the configuration.**

Equation $(3)$ can be generalized to a system of $N$ point charges $q_i$ located at position vectors $r_i$ ($i=1,2,...,N$):

$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]
{
W=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_o}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j\neq i=1}^N\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}
\qquad(4)
}
$$

where $r_{ij}$ is the separation between $r_i$ and $r_j$

> Would this be equivalent to integrating $kQ/r$ over the volume of a sphere?

By definition, the electrostatic self energy in this case would be the work done in assembling the electrons continuously throughout the volume of the sphere of radius $R$. We need to find the electric potential at the surface of the sphere (i.e., at $r=R$). Since we have a continuous system of charges here, we have to replace summation in equation $(4)$ by integration. But it's not equivalent to integrating $kQ/r$ over the volume of a sphere. What we are going to do is as follows:

We build up the sphere by adding subsequent infinitesimal layers of charge (carried from infinite distance). From Gauss’s theorem we know that, for an uniformly charged sphere having charge density $\rho$, radius $r$, and total charge $q=q(r)=\rho(4\pi r^3/3)$, the field and the potential outside the sphere are those of a point charge $q$ located in the center. On building the sphere, we are constructing infinitesimal layers of charge of size $dq=\rho4\pi r^2dr$, thereby increasing the radius of the sphere from $0$ to $R$. Hence the total energy is (from equation ($1$))

$$
\begin{align}
W=\int V(r)dQ&=\int_0^R k\frac{q(r)}{r}\rho 4\pi r^2dr\\
&=k\int_0^R\frac{\rho}{r} \left(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\right)4\pi r^2dr\\
&=\frac{4\pi\rho^2R^5}{15\epsilon_0}\\
&=\frac{3k}{5}\frac{Q^2}{R}
\end{align}
$$

where we have substituted for $\rho=Q/(4\pi R^3/3)$. So the electrostatic self energy in your problem is

$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid pink]
{
W=\frac{3k}{5}\frac{Q^2}{R}\qquad(5)
}
$$

where $Q$ is the total charge enclosed by the sphere. Equation ($5$) gives the energy stored in the system of charges to be assembled continuously throughout a spherical volume of radius $R$. All we have made use is just equation ($1$).

Comment: So, what is then, according to this, the electrostatic self-energy of an electron?

Comment: I have once heard that this self-energy is one of the infinities that plagued quantum electrodynamics...

Comment: I would like to stick my answer in the classical regime.