# Different forms for the formula of Electrostatic Energy for a two body system

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, potential-energy

I found this formula for total electric energy stored in a two body system in I.E. Irodov as
$$W= W_1 + W_2 + W_{12}\tag1$$

where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are self energies of the bodies and $W_{12}$ is the interaction energy of a body 1 and body 2.

---

1. Is equation (1) same as the formula:
   $$W= \int_{} \rho V d\tau\tag2$$
2. If so, then how can be get from equation (2) to (1)?

---

Note :-

1. Here I intend to include both body 1 and body 2 as a part of the continuous charge distribution in formula (2).

Comment: I think the first answer here will help you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281426/what-does-electrostatic-self-energy-mean

Comment: Equation 2 corresponds only to the interaction energy, it doesn't take into account the energy required to make the charge configuration.