# What is the difference between interaction energy and self-energy?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, definition, interactions, self-energy

From my understanding self-energy is the energy required to put charges in a certain charge distribution and interaction energy is the potential energy caused by the interactions between particles, but to me it seems like there isn't really a big difference between them and this post [What does electrostatic self-energy mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281426/) basically talks about them like they are the same thing.

My book says the total energy is the sum between the interaction energy and self-energy. I'm very confused.